# Excel worksheet names incorrect

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

I have a report that creates a separate excel worksheet for each group.

The property *`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name`* is set to the same field that is printed in the group header.

This does not work properly.  I have tried many different places to locate the sheet name property, but to no avail.

If there are 4 groups in sequence: GroupA, GroupB, GroupC, GroupD.  The worksheets in excel are named as follows: GroupD, GroupA, GroupA 2, GroupA 3.  The text box in the group header shows the correct value.

Below is the code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sales_log" language="groovy" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="a3911ab5-df01-4860-8519-007b2a6faecb">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select pd.CLASS_NAME,
       pd.CATEGORY_NAME,
       concat(pd.CLASS_CODE, pd.CATEGORY_CODE) as CLASSCAT,
       concat_ws(' ',
       case
            when substring(ph.SHIPPED_DATE,5,2) in ('01', '02', '03') then 'Q1'
            when substring(ph.SHIPPED_DATE,5,2) in ('04', '05', '06') then 'Q2'
            when substring(ph.SHIPPED_DATE,5,2) in ('07', '08', '09') then 'Q3'
            when substring(ph.SHIPPED_DATE,5,2) in ('10', '11', '12') then 'Q4'
            end, substring(ph.SHIPPED_DATE, 1, 4)) as QTR,
       date_format(str_to_date(ph.SHIPPED_DATE, '%Y%m%d'), '%m/%d/%Y') as SHIPPED_DATE,
       pd.PACK_SLIP_NO,
       ph.CUST_NAME,
       pd.ITEM_CODE,
       pd.ITEM_NAME,
       ifnull(round(pd.GROSS_WGT,2),0) as GROSS_WGT,
       ifnull(round(pd.TARE_WGT,2),0) as TARE_WGT,
       ifnull(round(pd.NET_WGT,2),0) as NET_WGT,
       ifnull(round(pd.PRICE,3),0) as PRICE,
       ifnull(round(pd.TOTAL_AMT,2),0) as TOTAL_AMT


from PACKSLIP_H ph
join PACKSLIP_D pd on ph.COMPANY_CODE=pd.COMPANY_CODE and ph.YARD_CODE=pd.YARD_CODE and ph.PACK_SLIP_NO=pd.PACK_SLIP_NO and pd.DETAIL_LINE_NO=''


where ph.SHIPPED_DATE>'20130101'


order by pd.CLASS_NAME, pd.CATEGORY_NAME, ph.SHIPPED_DATE]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CLASS_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CATEGORY_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CLASSCAT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="QTR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="SHIPPED_DATE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="PACK_SLIP_NO" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CUST_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ITEM_CODE" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ITEM_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="GROSS_WGT" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TARE_WGT" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="NET_WGT" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="PRICE" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="TOTAL_AMT" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="variable1" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="CategoryGroup">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{CATEGORY_NAME}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{CATEGORY_NAME}]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="CategoryGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CLASSCAT}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="59">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="6640b6e6-ae7e-49bb-aa7b-b0fb3a87f3ce" x="0" y="9" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="11" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CATEGORY_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="a02ed606-6e4a-4ae3-b40e-8015677d6d94" x="1" y="39" width="62" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="d4803c84-3e13-4016-aa99-6ac3406dbf14" x="90" y="39" width="141" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Customer]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="51a5e258-81f6-4c67-9b80-b62e4d274cdc" x="248" y="39" width="148" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Item    ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="f412ed46-2532-4008-a333-588d5d625299" x="407" y="39" width="65" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Gross]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="f406f52d-a722-465f-b95f-af94b82b6ac8" x="477" y="39" width="65" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Tare]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="1df16bed-f5b1-4c4c-901a-eb07a145ec8f" x="547" y="39" width="65" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Net]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="e15d0087-175b-4eaa-a574-cb55beb818b7" x="617" y="39" width="65" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Price]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement uuid="dba4e303-93da-421e-b12e-313d771b3560" x="687" y="39" width="65" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Ext.]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="9">
                <line>
                    <reportElement uuid="5f31c7b7-5d1d-402c-9cc5-b1ad239c8c37" x="1" y="5" width="100" height="1">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{CATEGORY_NAME}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <group name="QuarterGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{QTR}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="34">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="d3e8f4ec-0aa1-49a2-9de2-1aad34c7bb7d" x="1" y="7" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""+$F{QTR}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="535f2fe3-96d5-47b9-917d-8ff850c4ad02" x="23" y="0" width="62" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SHIPPED_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="a2597712-bb9a-45ee-b993-3dbb4911a0e0" x="90" y="0" width="141" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CUST_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="1a23c702-1fb7-4845-b231-ef2d75a97a16" x="407" y="0" width="65" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GROSS_WGT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="3160df9c-0680-433b-914c-690dda27d06f" x="477" y="0" width="65" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TARE_WGT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d8de4d49-c183-416d-9e10-9ce64b910f3a" x="547" y="0" width="65" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NET_WGT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bd238075-272f-42bd-b813-78dd4f3fe5ba" x="617" y="0" width="65" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRICE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="0bea29fb-f4a3-425f-b914-b661145d5c5d" x="243" y="0" width="153" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ITEM_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="b3707e2a-3dbe-4357-85de-d2b80eb70c68" x="687" y="0" width="65" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOTAL_AMT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Can anyone see the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I always set that property on a text field and it works. I use the last text field in Detail band.

**EDIT**
I've made an example with groups. I've set the property on text field in group header. Here is the code for example that works (query is for any oracle db but can be easily modified for any db)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="sales_log" language="groovy" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="a3911ab5-df01-4860-8519-007b2a6faecb">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="jodw"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select 'grp1' as grp, 1 as num from dual union all
select  'grp1' as grp, 3 as num from dual union all
select  'grp2' as grp, 2 as num from dual union all
select  'grp2' as grp, 4 as num from dual union all
select  'grp3' as grp, 6 as num from dual union all
select  'grp3' as grp, 8 as num from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="GRP" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="NUM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <group name="Group1" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{GRP}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="55">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="70" height="30" uuid="c3ed1fc8-a32a-46dc-9d76-ef153470a7ed">
                        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{GRP}]]></propertyExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{GRP}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="40" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="256" y="10" width="70" height="30" uuid="02da238f-37d8-42e8-a89e-2197414fef25"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="186" y="10" width="70" height="30" uuid="893f7401-3f3a-4091-9af9-9f42dfdb0634"/>
                <text><![CDATA[NUM]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I've tried that and still have the same problem.  Actually I've tried setting that property on every single element in the report and it still doesn't work.